# In rotational motion, can we assume the point masses system as continuous body systems?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I was solving a question of rotational motion given below:

> Four point masses, each of mass $m$, are fixed at the corners of a square of side $L$. The square is rotating with angular frequency $ω$, about an axis passing through one of the corners of the square and parallel to its diagonal. The angular momentum of the square about the axis is: …

The solution at the back of the book asked us to calculate the total moment of inertia of the system and then multiply it by $ω$, which results in the answer $3mL^2ω$.

Now if we assume this whole system as a square lamina (homogeneous solid square) of mass $3m$, we get the same answer. Is this just a coincidence and if not can anyone explain why this happened?

Comment: If the system rotates around the center, the angular momentum is less than $2mL^2\omega$. You can choose successive centers of rotation along a line passing through a corner. Angular momentum gets bigger and bigger as you get farther from the center. At some point, it equals $2mL^2\omega$. You can't say it is a coincidence in the probability sense that it happens at the corner. It may be surprising. It had to happen somewhere.

Comment: Apologies if I am wrong but I cannot find the solution to my doubt in this comment. I wanted to know if we assume this point mass system is a square sheet with continuous mass distribution and has a total mass of 3m. In this case, we will get the same answer. Can we generalize this assumption for all point mass systems?

Comment: The moment of inertia of a square lamina of mass $3m$, for a rotation about one of its corners, is $2 m L^2$, not $3 m L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The moment of inertia of any given geometric shape with a single scale parameter $L$ is of the form:
$$I = cmL^2,$$
where $c$ is a scalar constant that depends on the shape.
For example for a solid sphere and with $L$ being the radius, we have $c=\frac{2}{5}$.

Thus, if you take any two such shapes and name the mass ($m$) and scale parameter ($L$) the same, the moments of inertia only differ by a factor, namely the ratio of the constants $\frac{c}{c'}$. In your case, this factor happens to be ¾. Nothing special is going on.